# Has Vici CoolStorage been updated to work with WinRT / Metro?

Tags: orm, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, coolstorage

The project [website](http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home) does not indicate any support for WinRT.

Is there a way to do this? We (like many others, presumably) had bet on Vici CoolStorage for its cross-platform capabilities.

Comment: Why not ask/try it? https://github.com/viciproject/coolstorage

Comment: A version is in the works that will support .NET, Windows Phone 8, Windows 8 (RT), Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. It will be built as a PCL (portable class library).

Comment: Support for Windows Phone 7 will be dropped though

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert, that's great to hear. Please add your comments as an answer, and I'll accept it. Also, is there a rough ETA? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version is in the works that will support .NET 4.5, Windows Phone 8, WinRT (Windows 8), Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. It will be built as a PCL (portable class library). Support for Windows Phone 7 will be dropped because the platform lacks too many common .NET framework features that are available on other platforms.

This new version will be available early December.

Comment: is this ready for use? The website does not yet have any mention of these changes.

Comment: It is on GitHub but the release is not yet official

Comment: could you please provide any kind of update? Is the library usable currently? If not, what is the ETA? Many thanks.

Comment: It is usable and stable. I'm currently using it in my own projects without any issues

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Please look at my problem and help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669433/script-conflict-issue

Comment: @VigneshKumar That doesn't seem to be the correct link. At least it doesn't have anything to do with CoolStorage